# Caching of "multiple sites" with Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, html, offline-caching

I have this weird problem my website won't cache the mainsite!
Here is a little overview about what I am trying to do

The first page that is being loaded is the
[DidTheUserLoggedInBefore?.html]
which checks if the user already has logged in or not depending on that result the user will be redirected to
either [LOGIN.html] or [MAINPAGE.HTML]

pretty simple!

But here comes the problem when the user restarts the app in Offline mode the App should redirect immediately to the mainpage (assuming the previous login was a success).
But that doesnt happen at all.
Instead the [DidTheUserLoggedInBefore?.html] from cache was called (which is correct) and starts loading the mainpage which isnt in cache which results in a whitescreen aka my error.

So how do I get my App to cache the Mainpage?

I've tried setting CacheSize to 100, but that didn't changed a thing :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't check if the user has logged in with a .html file... You need some sort of server side language to set a cookie... Anyway this isn't much clear, is your "app" just a webview?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't let the webview cache more than 2 (simple) webpages...
WebView ignores he offline.manifest.php file too ...